# Send value of form to a function that is already running?

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to figure out a login to a website.  I've stopped the loading animation of a codrops template half way through and  I've been successful to have the login work as a prompt, but I can't figure out how to send the value from the form field to work the same way.  The function is already running...

Here is the link that works with the prompt
http://nmbdes.com/test/r2/

Here is the link that I am trying to have work with the form field.
http://nmbdes.com/test/r1/

password is "bianca"

Here is the relevant code-

**HTML**

```
  <div id="iWrap">
        <form>
            <label>Please Enter the Password</label><br />
            <input name="pw" id="pw" type="password" required><br />
            <input name="submit" id="submit" type="button" value="submit" onClick="epw();"/>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
function startLoading() {
        // simulate loading something..
        var simulationFn = function(instance) {
            var progress = 0,
                interval = setInterval( function() {
                    progress = Math.min( progress + Math.random() * 0.1, 1 );

                    instance.setProgress( progress );

                    // reached the end
                    if ( progress === 1) {

                        var apw = "bianca";
                        var epw = document.getElementById("pw").value;
                        if (ipw != epw) {
                            alert("Sorry, wrong password!");
                            window.location.reload();
                        } else if (ipw == epw) {
                            classie.remove( container, 'loading' );
                    classie.add( container, 'loaded' );
                    clearInterval( interval );

                    var onEndHeaderAnimation = function(ev) {
                        if( support.animations ) {
                            if( ev.target !== header ) return;
                            this.removeEventListener( animEndEventName, onEndHeaderAnimation ); 
                        }

                    classie.add( document.body, 'layout-switch' );
                    window.removeEventListener( 'scroll', noscroll );

                    }

                if( support.animations ) {
                    header.addEventListener( animEndEventName, onEndHeaderAnimation );
                } else {
                    onEndHeaderAnimation();
                }
            }   
                        }

                    }, 80);
    };
```

Is this possible or do I need to stick with the prompt?

thanks in advance for any help!
xx

Comment: What's the function that is called when submitted ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm overthinking your question, but it seems it's some basic html and javascript. 
If I understand, you want to submit the password from the form, and carry on with your logic.

You know,

> Writing event handlers in vanilla javascript can be annoying to make
>   work across browsers, so I'd recommend using a library like jquery to
>   make it robust (and also easier to write).

So the solution would be as simple as :

```
function startLoading() {
    // simulate loading something..
    var simulationFn = function(instance) {
        var progress = 0,
            interval = setInterval( function() {
                progress = Math.min( progress + Math.random() * 0.1, 1 );

                instance.setProgress( progress );

                // reached the end
                if ( progress === 1) {
                    $(form).submit(function(){
                        var apw = "bianca";
                        var epw = document.getElementById("pw").value;
                        if (ipw != epw) {
                            alert("Sorry, wrong password!");
                            window.location.reload();
                        } else if (ipw == epw) {
                            classie.remove( container, 'loading' );
                            classie.add( container, 'loaded' );
                            clearInterval( interval );

                            var onEndHeaderAnimation = function(ev) {
                                if( support.animations ) {
                                    if( ev.target !== header ) return;
                                    this.removeEventListener( animEndEventName, onEndHeaderAnimation );
                                }

                                classie.add( document.body, 'layout-switch' );
                                window.removeEventListener( 'scroll', noscroll );

                            }

                            if( support.animations ) {
                                header.addEventListener( animEndEventName, onEndHeaderAnimation );
                            } else {
                                onEndHeaderAnimation();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                }

            }, 80);
    };
```

**Important**

You also need to include jquery.

Comment: thanks so much!  i'm getting an error  - "uncaught syntaxerror: missing ) after argument list"

Comment: i believe the "  $(form).submit(function(){" isn't closed @sekai?